# How to turn on DX11 feature level 11.0

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm trying to run Dead by Daylight. I know I'm running DirectX 11, but it says feature level 11.0 is needed. how do I fix this? I am ready to post any log if necessary.

Comment: What is your GPU ? Is it a laptop with an integrated GPU and a separate dedicated GPU ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the DirectX Runtime you have installed which describes what the OS software can support is *not* the same thing as the Direct3D Hardware Feature Level which describes the support your video hardware provides. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) and [MSDN: Direct3D feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx)

For example, if you have Windows 7 installed, then you have the DirectX 11.0 Runtime or the [partial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687.aspx) DirectX 11.1 Runtime update. If you have Windows 8.1, then you have the DirectX 11.2 Runtime. With Windows 10, you have the DirectX 12.0 Runtime which supports 11.3 (or with the November 2015 build 10586, 11.4) as well as 12.0

The version of the DirectX Runtime doesn't indicate anything about whether or not the system is running a Direct3D 9-era Shader Model 2.0 part (which would be `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1` or `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2`), a Shader Model 3.0 part (`D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3`), a Direct3D 10 video card from 2006,(`D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0` or `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1`), a Direct3D 11 video card from 2010 (`D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`), or a just released latest card (`D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1`, `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0`, or `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1`). In fact, with Windows 10 an application can be using Directx 11.4 and in theory require a `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1` Direct3D Feature Level video card to run.

The game [system requirements](http://store.steampowered.com/app/381210/) state a minimum of *DX11 Compatible GeForce GTX 460 1GB or AMD HD 6850 1GB* which are 2010-era video cards. It expects you to have a PC gaming system with support for Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 11.0 or better video card. While it is possible that you have the wrong driver installed for your hardware, more likely you just don't have a recent or powerful enough GPU to support that title.

> Intel HD Graphics 4000/2500 (aka "Ivy Bridge" or "3rd generation Core") or later supports Direct3D Feature Level 11.0, but it may not be considered sufficient performance by the developer/publisher to support this particular title.

Comment: Thank you. at least I know I should upgrade my GPU.