# Directx 11 needs to feature level 11?

Tags: directx-11, amd-gpu

My friend has this problem here: 
[How to turn on DX11 feature level 11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182841/how-to-turn-on-dx11-feature-level-11-0)

I read the answer, but I don't understand. Could anyone elaborate what she should do? The previous problem was that the display driver was outdated, so I led her to the current driver. The next problem was that the DirectX was 12,(it needs to be 11) so I had her reinstall the driver. When my friend tries to open Dead by Daylight, a message pops up saying "DX11 feature level 11.0 is required to run the engine. She has AMD Radeon R4 Graphics. I'll provide any information that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

The AMD Radeon R4 supports `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0` according to a quick web search. It therefore should be able to support DirectX 11.x API using `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` or `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1` just fine. The same diver is used for both DirectX 11 an DirectX 12--assuming your friend is running Windows 10; Windows 7 will only ever support up to `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`.

When a game says "DX11 feature level 11.0 is required to run the engine." it means that it does not support [Direct3D Hardware feature level](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) devices 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 10.0, or 10.1.

If you have the Windows 10 SDK installed, you can run the `dxcapsviewer` tool to verify the support level for various APIs and feature levels.

All that said, it's an APU solution so it's low-end video card. Demanding games are likely to not work unless they are run at low quality settings.